# LLVM + gRPC compilation

Tags: makefile, compilation, cmake, llvm, google-cloud-bigtable

I am creating an LLVM pass which creates some calls to functions.

Right now, I was able to do this with external file (functions.c), which contains the functions to be called.

The structure:

- functions.c
- user.c
- build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so
  ...

This is the process I'm doing now:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm *.c   // compile
llvm-link -S -v -o single.ll *.ll    // link to single file
opt -load build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so -skeletonpass single.ll -o optimised.ll     // run the pass
llc optimised.ll     // create an executable
clang optimised.s
```

Now, I want to change these functions.c file with gRPC methods to call methods on Bigtable. I looked into some examples ([Hello World](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld), [Route Guide](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/route_guide)) and saw that the compilation and linking is done through makefiles.

**EDITED:**

I am using [Bigtable example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld) code and just want to adjust the existing CMakeLists.txt to do the commands above. In other words, I want to compile and link "all the Google code" and produce a single .ll file which I could run through LLVM pass.

I set

```
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

and added

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".bc") 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-S -emit-llvm")
```

options to CMakeLists.txt but it didn't produce .bc files.

Comment: Did you consider to consult the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)? The compiler and linker flags usage won't be different from what you are doing at the command line.

Comment: I added set(CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".bc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-S -emit-llvm") options but I doesn't produce .bc files

Comment: So you're doing that with CMake currently? Why didn't you mention that in your question? Show **everything** that's relevant to get helped please! Know your tools man!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, see the edit

Comment: Adding the [tag:cmake] tag and show your current `CMakeList.txt` would be helpful also.

Comment: I tried adding the lines mentioned above, but it didn't work, so I'm back with the original CMakeLists.txt provided in the Github repo.

Comment: Additional information needs to go inside your question, not into comments.

Comment: Nope! No chit chat ....

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck talking to Bigtable using the [Bigtable C++ client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/master/google/cloud/bigtable), since it is now GA (generally available) and fully-featured.

In particular, you may want to look at the [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/bigtable/CMakeLists.txt) file there, it could have hints on the correct LLVM flags to include in your compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I know of 2 alternatives:

- use [whole-program-llvm](https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm) if you're using Make files and you want to extract bitcode archives, etc.
- use [llvm-ir-cmake-utils](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) if you want to do something similar with CMake; you'll have to adjust/augment your `CMakeLists.txt` with the offered calls (there are examples in this repo).